# function immutable parameter overriding

Tags: python, parameters, overriding, mutable

function parameter use mutable type
-> error) multiple values for argument

Jupyter-note

https://docs.python.org/ko/3/tutorial/controlflow.html

```
def parrot(voltage, state='a stiff', action='voom', type='Norwegian Blue'):
    print("-- This parrot wouldn't", action, end=' ')
    print("if you put", voltage, "volts through it.")
    print("-- Lovely plumage, the", type)
    print("-- It's", state, "!")
```

```
parrot(110, voltage=220)
```

```
def parrot(voltage, state='a stiff', action='voom', type='Norwegian Blue'):
    print("-- This parrot wouldn't", action, end=' ')
    print("if you put", voltage, "volts through it.")
    print("-- Lovely plumage, the", type)
    print("-- It's", state, "!")
```

why parameter variable can user mutable type override?

```
parrot({1,2,}, voltage={})
```

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 parrot({1,2,}, voltage={})
      2 # ???

TypeError: parrot() got multiple values for argument 'voltage'

Comment: can not reproduce... also `parrot(110, voltage=220)` fails (python 3.6).

Comment: btw; this is the link to the doc in english (probably easier to understand for most people here): https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#more-on-defining-functions

Answer (score 1):

The reason you get that error is that in the function definition, your first parameter is `voltage`.  When you call `parrot`, the first argument you pass in this call statement will be given to `voltage`.

Now, in `parrot(110,voltage=220)`, you are giving `voltage` 2 different values, 110 and 220. This will naturally raise an error. You will get the same error even for `parrot({1,2,}, voltage={})`, again, for the same reason.

You can fix this by removing either argument in either of your function calls.

Comment: i think the OP understood that; the question is why does it work for `parrot(110, voltage=220)` (which i can not reproduce) and not for `parrot({1,2,}, voltage={})`.

Comment: Both calls are invalid in Python 3.6.8. Both function calls return the same error: ```parrot() got multiple values for argument 'voltage'```

Comment: yup, that is what i said. but for the OP the first case seems to work somehow.

Comment: functional arguments struct at function local dict type varialbes, dict type variation must have unique keys, so {"voltage":{1,2,}, "voltage":{}} -> dict keys error

Comment: Yes, a dictionary needs to have unique keys, so you can't have two keys with the name 'voltage'